# Trying to get c++ compiler and getting permission denied

Tags: windows, bash

So I am trying to make an irc bot using libircclient.  To do this I need the c++ libraries.

I do this by using

sudo apt-get install g++ libcurl4-openssl-dev

The problem is when I do this I get a ton of errors saying

Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com' and variations of that

So I typed in apt-get update and got these errors

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Before I even typed in my password I did get this error though

sudo: unable to resolve host

Result of Hostname -

DESKTOP-OEHHKKI

/etc/hostname

bash: /etc/hostname: Permission denied

Comment: have you tried sudo -s first then running commands? Long shot but worth a try

Comment: same issue happened

Comment: Please add to your question the output of `hostname`,  `less /etc/hostname` and `less /etc/hosts`

Comment: Done.  Both of the last two give me permission denied.  The host name isn't what I use to log in to bash either, which is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/hostname` has been messed up, in order to fix it:

**1.** **Open a text editor with  root permissions**: `sudo -H gedit /etc/hostname`

And edit the opened file to ONLY contain your machine name, which you can figure out running `hostname`.

**2.** You also need to modify this file `/etc/hosts`, using the same method `sudo -H gedit /etc/hosts`, so that it looks like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   YOUR-MACHINE-NAME
```

You can use `sudo` even if the message `unable to resolve host` appears. Just enter your password as usual and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**3.** Reboot.